# Async background-image: url(...) with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider that I have a API that fetches a list of blog post, and each post has their own background image link.

```
<article ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{ post.meta.cover }})'}" ng-repeat="post in blog.listOfPost">
```

The *post.meta.cover* url will be fetch asynchronously.

Even though everything *works*, I get an error every time the page loads because the url is not fetch yet.

```
 Cannot set property 'backgroundImage' of undefined
```

Question: How can I delay the parsing html until all the data is loaded from the api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're waiting for the url you can just check against it:

```
<article ng-style="post.meta.cover ? {'background-image': 'url(' + post.meta.cover + ')'} : {}" ng-repeat="post in blog.listOfPost">
```